# How to install sbt package for Jupyter notebook with Scala kernel?

Tags: scala, jupyter-notebook, sbt, jupyter

I am using Jupyter notebook with Scala kernel? How can I install sbt package and load it for the notebook?

It seems this https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Scripts.html is related.

Answer (score 3):

late answer, but likely you would like to use [Almond](https://almond.sh/) as a Scala kernel. Simply import sbt packages with [ivy](https://ammonite.io/#import$ivy), e.g.:

```scala
import $ivy.`org.scalaz::scalaz-core:7.2.27`, scalaz._, Scalaz._
```

Answer (score 0):

Great solution, @Joost Döbken ! Also, I confirmed that I successfully imported:

```scala
import $ivy.`org.scalanlp::breeze:1.1`, breeze.linalg._
```